# How to create a collapsible div in absolute position using angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to create a collapsible div using angular-material which should be fixed to the bottom left corner like shown on the image below.

Is that actually possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use CSS - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/JRoajv)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-fill>
  <div id="chatWindow" layout="column" style="height:{{status==='Open'?'50px':'200px'}}">
    <md-button ng-click="toggle()">{{status}}</md-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.status = "Open";
  $scope.toggle = function () {
    $scope.status = ($scope.status === "Open") ? "Close" : "Open";
  }
});
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: purple;
}

#chatWindow {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is doable. There is a github repository if you want to implement chat window like you are saying.

> https://github.com/irontec/angular-bootstrap-simple-chat

But, if you want to tweak yourself then here is the code for `collapsable` div. Good luck.

> http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/eK8X5/7/

Comment: Thanks for the example. But i am using angular-material and the examples are bootstrap.